# Store GUID in MySQL from C#

Tags: c#, mysql

Trying to persist Guid's in a MySQL db from C# (.NET). MySQL column is of type BINARY(16). Any sugestion on how to persist the guid and later get the guid back to from MySQL? Looking for a code answer here :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Figured it out. Here's how ...

Database schema

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (                                            
     `id` BINARY(16) NOT NULL,                                      
     PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)                                            
)
```

Code

```
string connectionString = string.Format("Server={0};Database={1};Uid={2};pwd={3}", "server", "database", "user", "password");

Guid orgId = Guid.NewGuid();
Guid fromDb = Guid.Empty;

using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();

    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES (?id)", conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("id", MySqlDbType.Binary).Value = orgId.ToByteArray();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT id FROM test", conn))
    {
        using (MySqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            r.Read();
            fromDb = new Guid((byte[])r.GetValue(0));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need not do it in two separate queries. Datareader alone would suffice which would do all operations and finally return the read value

Comment: and somehow this did not work when I tried. see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032071/how-to-get-uuid-generated-by-mysql-into-a-c-sharp-variable/10174083#10174083

Answer (score 5):

Apparently, the `GetGuid()` method in MySQL .NET Connector v5.2.6+ should be fixed so you can [use this example](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=41452).

Comment: You mean MySQL .Net connector v5.2.6+. Right?

Answer (score 2):

**1)** You can insert it the way @Tim Skauge does. But while selecting the .Net connector version is important. When I had used v 5.2.1, I needed to do only this:

```
using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT id FROM test", conn))
{
    using (MySqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        r.Read();
        Guid id = (Guid)r[0];
    }
}
```

Here the reader itself reads the binary value to .NET `Guid` type. You can see it if you check the type of `r[0]`. But with newer version, ie, 6.5.4, I found the type to be `byte[]`.. ie, it gets the binary value from db to its corresponding byte array. So you do this:

```
using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT id FROM test", conn))
{
    using (MySqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        r.Read();
        Guid id = new Guid((byte[])r[0]);
    }
}
```

You can read why is it so [here in documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-connection-options.html). The alternative to read Guid type directly and not as byte[] is to have this line : `Old Guids=true` in your connection string.

**2)** Additionally you can do this straight away to read the binary value as string by asking MySQL to do the conversion, but in my experience this method is slower.

Insert:

```
using (var c = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES (UNHEX(REPLACE(@id,'-','')))", conn))
{
    c.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    c.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

or

```
using (var c = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES (UNHEX(@id))";, conn))
{
    c.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"));
    c.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

And select:

```
using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT hex(id) FROM test", conn))
{
    using (MySqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        r.Read();
        Guid id = new Guid((string)r[0]);
    }
}
```

The one thing you need to notice is that if you are inserting Guids by `hex` method then you got to read it by the `unhex` approach. If you are inserting them relying on .NET's `ToByteArray()` method, then you got to read similarly. Otherwise you will get incorrect guids read since .NET has a peculiar way of ordering the bytes according to endianness. [Catch something about it here in the context of inserting and reading Guids in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177514/incorrect-guid-order)