# Is MySQL Connector/Net backward compatible?

Tags: mysql, backwards-compatibility, mysql-connector

If I have a MySQL server 5.1, can I use all the onnectors from version 5.1 and above?:

- Connector/Net 6.1
- Connector/Net 6.0
- Connector/Net 5.2
- Connector/Net 5.1

Clicking http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/ defaults to 6.0...

Comment: Good question and I wonder what happens if you deploy the 6.0.2 assembly on a machine with 6.1.0 installed!

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is, pretty much.. [See the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-net-versions.html). You can also confirm it by going to the download page of each connector and then clicking versions of MySQL on left side of the page (which is the documentation library). It doesnt load for versions prior to MySQL 5.0, but loads for all other versions.

The real caveat is .NET connector itself exhibits different behaviours with different versions. [See for one such](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10681245/661933)..

Answer (score 1):

If it helps even partially: I am running MySql 5.1.33 (via an installation of wampserver), and am using Connector/Net 6.0.3.0 with no problems (so far!).